# Ошибка "Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource not found" в Magento2

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, ecommerce

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно зарыть баг который заключается в том что плагин при загрузке страницы с настройками выдает:

```
Zend_Acl_Exception: Resource 'Vendor_Extension::settings' not found
```

Исходя из текста я понимаю что проблема заключается в отсутствии ресурса но путь ее решения я не нашел.

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение проблемы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо добавить указанный в ошибке ресурс в файле `app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/acl.xml` вида:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Vendor_Extension::settings" title="Имя вашего ресурса, видимое для администратора" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

и добавить разрешение на использование этого ресурса для админ-роли (если используется) в настрйоках *System > Permissions > User Roles > Роль для которой задается настрйока > Role Resources*.

Comment: Вообще это случается каждый раз при переходе на любой пункт меню

Comment: @IvanHanenko скорее всего причина тому попытка обращения к блоку\контроллеру вашего модуля, в котором ресурс явно указан и не существует. Вы можете добавить в вопрос данные из вашего файла `app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/acl.xml` ?

Comment: как только доберусь до исходников - сразу оповещу что добавил